Django rest frame-work error : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Router with basename X is already registered , despite it is not
In my django app am using DRF and it gives me , and it gives me this strange error when i try to run the app :
water_maps  |     router.register(r'breaches_edit_delete', api.BreacEditDeletehViewSet)
water_maps  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 59, in register
water_maps  |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)
water_maps  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Router with basename "breach" is already registered. Please provide a unique basename for viewset "<class 'water_maps_dashboard.api.BreacEditDeletehViewSet'>"


despite there is no duplication and the routers ,, here is my URLS file :
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from . import api
from . import views
from .api import check_current_version, check_for_device_id, check_for_login, get_cords_ids

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("main_depart", api.MainDepartmentViewSet)
router.register("job_description", api.JobDescriptionViewSet)
# router.register("section", api.SectionViewSet)
router.register("city", api.CityViewSet)
router.register("AppUser", api.AppUserViewSet)
router.register("Breach", api.BreachViewSet)
router.register("Section", api.SectionViewSet)
router.register("MapLayers", api.MapLayersViewSet)
router.register("LayersCategory", api.LayersCategoryViewSet)
router.register("UserMessage", api.UserMessageViewSet)
router.register("about_us", api.AboutUsViewSet)
# router.register(r'breaches_edit_delete', api.BreacEditDeletehViewSet)
router.register(r'edit_delete_breach', api.BreacEditDeletehViewSet)

urlpatterns = (

    path("api/do_search/", api.do_search, name="do_search"),
    path("api/activate_account/", api.activate_account, name="activate_account"),
    path("api/user_login/", api.user_login, name="user_login"),
    path("api/create_app_user/", api.create_app_user, name="create_app_user"),
    path("api/save_breaches/", api.save_breaches, name="save_breaches"),
    path("api/add_cords_to_breach/", api.add_cords_to_breach, name="add_cords_to_breach"),
    path("api/do_forgot_password/", api.do_forgot_password, name="do_forgot_password"),
    path("api/reset_password/", api.reset_password, name="reset_password"),
    path("api/get_my_breaches/", api.get_my_breaches, name="get_my_breaches"),
    path("api/map_view/", api.map_view, name="map_view"),
    path("api/post_user_message/", api.post_user_message, name="post_user_message"),
    path("api/add_edit_request/", api.add_edit_request, name="add_edit_request"),
    path("api/request_delete_account/", api.request_delete_account, name="request_delete_account"),
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
    path("api/check_for_login/", check_for_login, name="check_for_login"),
    path("api/check_for_device_id/", check_for_device_id, name="check_for_device_id"),
    path("api/check_current_version/", check_current_version, name="check_current_version"),
    path("api/get_cords_ids/", get_cords_ids, name="get_cords_ids"),
    path("upload_data/", views.upload_data, name="upload_data"),
    path("admin_logs/", views.admin_logs, name="admin_logs"),
    path("trigger_task/", views.admin_logs, name="trigger_task"),
    path("send_email/", views.send_email_to_users, name="send_email"),
    path("api/the_map/", api.show_map, name="the_map"),
    path("reset_device_id/",views.reset_device_id,name="reset_device_id"),
    path("create-folder/",views.create_folder,name="create_folder"),
    path("get_folders_and_drawings/",views.fetch_folders_and_drawings,name="get_folders_and_drawings"),
    path("get_connected_water_elements/",views.get_connected_water_elements,name="get_connected_water_elements"),
    path('verify/<int:app_user_id>/', views.verify_otp_view, name='verify_otp'),
    path("api/get_map_layers_count/", api.get_map_layers_count, name="get_map_layers_count"),

)

api views
.....

class BreachViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the Breach class"""

    queryset = models.Breach.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BreachSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

class BreacEditDeletehViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Breach.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.BreachEditDeleteSerializer

@permission_classes(["IsAuthenticated"])
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_breaches(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'][6:]
        text = request.data['text']
        admin_area_name = request.data['admin_area_name']
        # breach_area_data = request.data['breach_area_data']
        date = request.data['date'] 
        time = request.data['time']
        cont = request.data['cont'] 
        others = request.data['others'] 
        breach_area_appointments = request.data['breach_area_appointments']
        trophies_fault = request.data['trophies_fault']
        city_id = request.data['city_id']
        helpers = request.data['helpers']
        image = None
        image_2 = None
        if 'image' in request.data:
            image = request.data['image']
        if 'image_2' in request.data:
            image_2 = request.data['image_2']
        city_object = models.City.objects.get(id=city_id)
        main_user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        app_user = models.AppUser.objects.get(user=main_user)
        new_breach = models.Breach.objects.create(
            app_user=app_user, text=text, admin_area_name=admin_area_name,
            breach_area_appointments=breach_area_appointments,
            trophies_fault="مكافأة" if trophies_fault == "0" else "محاسبة" if trophies_fault == "1" else "قبول أداء",city=city_object,image=image,image_2=image_2,
            helpers=helpers,date=date,time=time,main_contributors=cont,others=others)
        data = {"success": True, "breach_id": new_breach.id}
        return Response(data, headers=get_headers())


@permission_classes(["IsAuthenticated"])
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_cords_to_breach(request):
    """
    add cords to breach
    """
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # try:
        breach_id = request.data['breach_id']
        breach_object = models.Breach.objects.get(id=breach_id)
        cords = request.data['cords']
        kml = simplekml.Kml()
        lineCords = []
        for item in cords:
            new_cord = models.BreachCords.objects.create(
                latlng=item, breach=breach_object)
            theLat = float(item.split(",")[0])
            theLng = float(item.split(",")[1])
            kml.newpoint(name=item.split(",")[0], coords=[(theLat, theLng)])
            lineCords.append((theLat, theLng))
        lin = kml.newlinestring(name="", description="",
                                coords=lineCords)
        theDIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, f'kml_files/')
        new_kml = kml.save(f'{theDIR}{breach_id}.kml')
        with open(f'{theDIR}{breach_id}.kml') as f:
            breach_object.kml_file.save(f"{breach_id}.kml", File(f))
        create_report_file(breach_object)
        data = {"success": True, }
        return Response(data, headers=get_headers())
    
@permission_classes(["IsAuthenticated"])
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_my_breaches(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'][6:]
        main_user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        app_user = models.AppUser.objects.get(user=main_user)
        my_breaches = models.Breach.objects.filter(app_user=app_user)
        data = {
            "success": True,
            "details": serializers.BreachSerializer(my_breaches, many=True).data
        }
        return Response(data, headers=get_headers())





This is happening because both of your viewsets class doing the same job, also you define method for doing some of the same work.
If you use ModelViewSet then don't need to declare individual post, get, put, patch, delete methods view class. following code is enough for everything. But if you wan't more accesss and to do custom thing then using individual viewclass or function is preferable. Also you can customize your viewset class for these things. But to solve your problem keep the following code and give it a try.
api view
class BreachViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""ViewSet for the Breach class"""

queryset = models.Breach.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.BreachSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

router
router.register("Breach", api.BreachViewSet)

To learn more about viewsets check here
